# Nativescript - Android disabling physical device back button

Tags: android, nativescript, back, nativescript-angular

I am trying to disabling the physical device back in `android` only in some screens. Trying the below code is not working. Any idea?

```
import { RouterExtensions } from "nativescript-angular";
  import * as application from "application";
  import { AndroidApplication, AndroidActivityBackPressedEventData } from "application";
  import { isAndroid } from "platform";

  export class ItemComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private router: Router) {}

    ngOnInit() {
      if (!isAndroid) {
        return;
      }
      application.android.on(AndroidApplication.activityBackPressedEvent, (data: AndroidActivityBackPressedEventData) => {

          data.cancel = true; // prevents default back button behavior

      });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   if (!shouldAllowBack()) {
       doSomething();
   } else {
       super.onBackPressed();
   }
}
```

Comment: An explanation, what the posted code does and how this addresses the problem in the question, rarely fails to improve an answer.

Comment: This is the native way implement it. The required solutions needs to be in NativeScript

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your activity-

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
       // Your Code Here. Leave empty if you want nothing to happen on back press.

}
```

For more information visit [this](https://hackernoon.com/disable-android-home-back-and-active-apps-buttons-f7450dfeddcd) link.

Answer (score 0):

Back button is controlled at Activity level, NativeScript uses one single Activity and all your pages / routes are fragments inside that.

So you don't have to call it on every page / component. Add the listener to your app component and check the router to know which page you are at and cancel the back event.

Answer (score 0):

Use `location` and check if location consists the desired path(as mentioned in routing file) where you want to use your custom function.

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
```

constructor(private _location: Location
       ){}

```
if (application.android) {
            application.android.on(AndroidApplication.activityBackPressedEvent, (data: AndroidActivityBackPressedEventData) => {
                const path = this._location.path();

            console.log(`path i s--> ${path}`);
            switch (path) {
                case '/Screen 1':
                    data.cancel = true;
                    break;
                case '/Screen 2':
                    //do something else
                    break;
            });
        }
```